# Select an Email from Emails provided via B2C custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

the sample here is not working and missing the azure function, any remarks on that: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/selectemail

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A good question explains what you've done, shows the code you've tried and the errors you received, how it failed etc. If you update your question with that information, I'm sure you'll get more answers.

Comment: Hi.Can it be more detailed? Or provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the REST API yourself.
The interface of the REST API is in the readme.

The REST API needs to respond with a JSON Array:

```
{
    "emails": [
        "email1@contoso.com",
        "email2@contoso.com",
        "email3@notrealemail.com"
    ]
}
```

To augment the sample, you would add an `inputClaim` to the `Get-Emails` technical profile to send an identifier in JSON to your REST API. Then your REST API can respond with an appropriate response in the format above.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or any guidance that takes us through that process step by step ... failed to craft this rest api